# getPosition in Fragment v4

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I use android.support.v4.app.Fragment and inside my Fragment child class I would like to get the fragment position, something like:

```
public abstract class MyFragment extends Fragment {

   public void process () {
      .....
      getPosition();
```

The problem is that there is no any getPosition equivalent function in Android. How to get the position (the same as in the fragment below)?

```
public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

     public Fragment getItem(int position) {
         .....
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the position as an argument to your fragment when you create it from the PagerAdapter:

```
public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

     public Fragment getItem(int position) {
         return MyFragment.newInstance(position);
     }
     //...
}
```

And:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

  int position;

  public static MyFragment newInstance(int position) {
    MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("Position", position);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
  }

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    position = getArguments().getInt("Position");
  }
}
```